# Flutter iOS adding UNNotificationServiceExtension to the app

Tags: flutter, apple-push-notifications, unnotificationserviceextension

I'm trying to alter the push notification received via APNs before showing it to the user, and I feel like UNNotificationServiceExtension is the answer... but I can't find a way to trigger the didReceive function even if I add the extension through XCode -> File -> Target -> Notification Service Extension... Help me please

note: I'm not using FCM for iOS...